# boot loader trouble

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've installed ubuntu gnome and it won't let me run the grub2 boot loader from my hard drive when I start the computer and then would try to start using a lan network and would restart the boot process again. I burned disk with grub2 using http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

If I boot off of that disk I can select ubuntu and boot it but I can't boot without this disk because the default grub2 boot loader will not start on boot.

I'd like to be able to boot my computer without this disk.

pastebin link: http://paste2.org/jJHJ0sB9

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: You might try turning UEFI Secure boot off in UEFI. But make sure you are booting in UEFI boot mode, not BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. You somehow installed a grub BIOS boot loader to gpt's protective MBR, but it will never work. Just do not boot in BIOS mode and the incorrect grub will never be seen.

Comment: how do i do that, im looking it up not but i cannot find a simple explanation.

Comment: plus i no longer have windows installed so i can't edit the UEFI from there

Comment: i tried to run `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` and it gave me this error: "Cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reinstalling grub2 from boot repair. First it gave me an error saying

```
Failed to open /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi - Not Found
```

I then realised I could go into the foler `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` to find the GRUB file where it had been reinstalled  and then copy `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`, `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` and `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` to the folder it said it could not find the files in which was `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/`

After I did that my computer will now correctly boot GRUB when booting from the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable USB of Ubuntu, boot from it then.
Use the commands given in this link [Repair/Reinstall/Restore Grub](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: my laptop will not let me boot from usb, it is an option in the bios but not in the multi boot menu and will not boot at all

Comment: this is the pastebin link for my boot http://paste2.org/jJHJ0sB9